# jquery hide-nav on scroll in react

Tags: jquery, reactjs, scroll, header, nav

My normal jquery code is working perfectly fine in react.

When I try to execute this perfectly working jquery code in react, It is simply not working.

1) Navigation.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import $ from 'jquery';
import './Navigation.scss';

class nav extends Component {

    componentDidMount = () => {
        // Hide Header on on scroll down
        var didScroll;
        var lastScrollTop = 0;
        var delta = 5;
        var navbarHeight = $('header').outerHeight();

        $(window).scroll(function(event){
            didScroll = true;
        });

    setInterval(function() {
        if (didScroll) {
            hasScrolled();
            didScroll = false;
        }
    }, 250);

    function hasScrolled() {
        var st = $(this).scrollTop();

        // Make sure they scroll more than delta
        if(Math.abs(lastScrollTop - st) <= delta) {
            return;
        }

        // If they scrolled down and are past the navbar, add class .nav-up.
        // This is necessary so you never see what is "behind" the navbar.
        if (st > lastScrollTop && st > navbarHeight){
            // Scroll Down
            $("header").removeClass("nav-down").addClass("nav-up");
        } else {
            // Scroll Up
            if(st + $(window).height() < $(document).height()) {
                $("header").removeClass("nav-up").addClass("nav-down");
            }
        }

        lastScrollTop = st;
    }

}

render() {

    return (
        <header className="fixed-top">
            <nav id="small-top-nav" className="nav navbar navbar-expand-lg nav-down">

                /* ALL LINKS CODE */

            </nav>

        </header>
    );
}

export default nav;
```

2) Navigation.scss

```
.nav-up {
    top: -2.5rem;
}

.nav-down {
    down: 2.5rem;
}
```

I tried this jquery code in normal bootstrap and working fine.

You can also find this working jquery code [here](https://codepen.io/kaemak/pen/mHyKa/) on codepen.

Comment: react uses a virtual dom to detect DOM changes, so i think that it is not that simple to change the real DOM directly. Also it is not recommended to manipulate the real DOM directly at all.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the way to do things in react. If you even have JQuery imported, you're probably doing it wrong. 
You don't want to manipulate the actual DOM here, that misses the point of using react. Nor should you change elements visibility to determine which elements are seen by the client.
 
Instead, you should have a state that determines wheather the component should be rendered, a function to set the state accordingly (in your case, when the client scrolls), and a ternary expression inside your render method (`{ this.state.showNav ? <Nav /> : null }`)

Comment: True! The difference between manipulation of virtual DOM and actual DOM should be understood deeply in this case.